# Questions about malloc

Tags: c, malloc, sizeof

Can someone explain these portion of code to me please? Correct me if I am wrong.

```
int *longest = malloc(sizeof(int)); 
*longest =0;
```

Does this mean:

1. Return a pointer points to the beginning of a memory block whose size is 4 byte (for 32bit machine)? Why not just write `malloc(4)`?
2. For the second line, does it mean that longest is a pointer of 4 byte block, start at 0?

Comment: Is this for C or C++? You should include one tag or the other with this question to make it clear, and make it show up in searches and the like. Also, if it is C++, you should use `new` instead.

Answer (score 6):

1. Yes, it gets exactly enough memory for one `int`. You should avoid explicitly assuming a given size - it makes it a nightmare to port to other platforms in the future. You spotted it yourself - `sizeof(int)` won't always be 4 everywhere.
2. No, this assigns the value 0 to the newly allocated memory, which was pointed to by `longest`. The `*` here is the dereference operator, it informally says "I want to work with the thing this pointer points to".

Comment: Just a little add on, there is even a better idiom for that particular allocation case: `int *longest = malloc(sizeof(*longest));` This avoids to repeat the type, so if one day the type is change, everyting is still consistent.